# Group .net project: 1 Developer on PC with VS 2005 and 1 Developer on Mac with MonoDeveloper

Tags: monodevelop

I'm new to .net but a mac user. I need to team with a friend on a new project. He's currently on a pc using VS 2005. And I'd rather try Mono as oppose to running xp or vista in a VM and install VS there.

If I use Mono Developer. will we be able to share files in the same project? Is the current version of Mono Developer the equivalent of VS 2005 or 2008?

Please advise on the best way for me to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Kevykev

Answer (score 3):

Current MonoDevelop can read and write both VS2005 and VS2008 project files, and do not automatically convert them. There is no problem with sharing solutions between VS and MD.

I am working on such project, where I'm using MD under Linux and other developer is using VS on Windows. There are no problems with it. I prefer this solution then running VS in virtual system, because of the native feel of the application and no barriers between virtual system and my native desktop.

Comment: I just started to test out my open source project on Mono/openSUSE, and it is fine to work on Windows/Visual Studio, and openSUSE/MonoDevelop without any issues (but it takes a while to make the solution/project files initially).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the nature of your project that could work, but honestly, if you are working on a shared project, having both developers working on the same platform is most likely going to give you the best overall end solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding... And you're likely correct.. we're on a tight deadline as it is.. and i dont want to create more obstacles with integrating files from different workspaces... Vmware Fusion it is  :(

Thx Kevin